# Trying to use multiprocessing module fails with TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use `Pool` from `multiprocessing` module to call a function in parallel and it fails with these errors. Searching around gives me no clue how to solve the issue. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401099/python-multiprocessing-typeerror-new-missing-1-required-positional-argum) 
is a similar question with no response.

Here is my the Traceback:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'
```

---

What I'm doing is simple. I've got a list of IDs which I was passing to a function using a for loop and everything was working fine:

```
def do_the_job(self, id):
  pass
  # Process ID
  # Add ID to a list
  # Do a network activity related to id    

def main(self):
  for id in self.lst:
    self.do_the_job(id)
```

And because it was not able to use all my network capacities I changed the loop part as below after importing `Pool` from `multiprocessing` to run it in parallel. But it fails as it hits `p.map(...)` with the errors reported above. Is there anyway to diagnose the issue?

```
def main(self):
  with Pool(2) as p:
    p.map(self.do_the_job, self.lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at Traceback we can spot:

```
return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'
```

That's what happen when you pass a datatype that can not be pickled which is necessary for `Pool` to work.

By checking your list elements, make sure all of its items are consisted from Python's standard datatype.

That was the actual problem here.